# Haskell: Random Coin Instance

Tags: haskell, random, generator

I have defined a `Coin` data type:

```
data Coin = H | T
    deriving (Bounded, Eq, Enum, Ord, Show)
```

I now have to write a Random Coin instance, given the following framework:

```
instance Random Coin where
randomR (l, h) g = undefined
random           = undefined
```

Obviously, this random instance should return either H or T. I'm beginning to start understanding how Monads work, however, I'm confused about the initial random generator. I get that a random generator returns a `(a, gen)`, but where do we get the initial generator to create a first random Coin? I currently have the following:

```
instance Random Coin where
randomR (l, h) g = case randomR(l, h) g of
                   (c, g') -> (c, g')
random           = getStdRandom(randomR(minBound :: Coin, maxBound :: Coin))
```

I'm especially confused about the `random` function, since particular expression seems to return type IO Coin. Any help to enlighten me is much appreciated!

Comment: `case foo of (x, y) -> (x, y)` is the same as `case foo of anything -> anything`, which is the same as `foo`. So you're left with `randomR (l, h) g = randomR (l, h) g` in your instance. Looks like a very fancy infinite loop to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of the [`Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random) class is that its methods give you a generator then ask you to make the next value and generator. Whenever your class derives both `Enum` and `Bounded` there is actually a boilerplate method for making a random instance:

```
instance Random Coin where
  randomR (lo, hi) g = let (a, g') = randomR (fromEnum lo, fromEnum hi) g in (toEnum a, g')
  random = randomR (minBound, maxBound)
```

(In fact, there is [already a package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-derive-0.1.0.0/docs/System-Random-TH.html) that does exactly this for you.)

Comment: Thanks Alec. Why does `randomR (minBound, maxBound)` in the `random` function does not need a generator? Its function takes both a pair and a generator right?

Comment: @Felix: That’s a case of eta-reduction. `random g = something g` is equivalent to `random = something`. Similarly, `\x -> f x` is equivalent to `f`, because the lambda just passes its argument along to `f`.

Answer (score 4):

The functions you are defining have types

```
randomR :: RandomGen g => (Coin, Coin) -> StdGen -> (Coin, StdGen)
random  :: RandomGen g => StdGen                 -> (Coin, StdGen)
```

In other words, you're already given a random generator -- the second argument of randomR and the first of random. Any attempt to get a system random generator will cause a type error, because suddenly you've added IO into the mix, and that occurs nowhere in these types.

Usually, random instances translate one of the Integer-based functions into the specific types needed. For instance, we could use

```
 randomR :: (RandomGen g) => (Integer, Integer) -> g -> (Integer, g)
```

to produce a number in the range (0,1) and translate 0 into `H` and 1 into `T`.

```
instance Random Coin where
  randomR (low,high) generator =
    case randomR (toInt low, toInt high) generator of
      (i,g) -> (toCoin i, g)
   where
    toInt :: Coin -> Integer
    toInt H = 0
    toInt T = 1
    toCoin 0 = H
    toCoin 1 = T
```

I'll leave `random` for you to define.

By the way, you might realize that this is basically the same instance that `Bool` must have, so a sensible way to solve your problem would also have been to check the [source code for the "random" package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/src/System-Random.html) and search for "instance Random Bool".

Afterwards, you could use it with any random generator, like so:

```
> let gen = mkStdGen 1 in take 10 $ randomRs (H,T) gen
[T,T,T,H,H,T,H,H,H,T]
```

Comment: I initially referred to a function that isn't actually exported from the module, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks Sarah. I'm not sure if I'm missing a very simple point, but since we're instantiating 'randomR', how exactly am I already given a random generator? Is this generator already defined in the Random class?

Comment: No, it is simply an argument to the function you're definining. `randomR (low, high) gen = foo` is essentially saying: Given values (low,high) and gen, I can give you foo.

When you actually use the function (ie. not when you define it) you will have to supply it with such a generator.

Comment: @Felix I've added an example. And fixed a bug. ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit cleaner (less partial functions) to use the `Random Bool` instance instead of `Random Int`? The only reason I used the latter in my answer is because is extends to anything that is `Enum` and `Bounded`...

Comment: @Alec Yes, I absolutely think so. I chose `Integer` because of the infinite number of possible values, so that this approach might be used for any `Random` instance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I liked [Alec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40063424/712526)'s implementation so much, I made it my own. By defining the `random` and `randomR` functions separately, it is easier to use for multiple instances (less boilerplate!) — and for my money — easier to read, too.

```
import Control.Arrow (first)

boundedRandom :: (Bounded b, Random b, RandomGen g) => g -> (b, g)
boundedRandom = randomR (minBound, maxBound)

enumRandomR :: (Enum e, RandomGen g) => (e,e) -> g -> (e,g)
enumRandomR (min,max) g = toEnum `first` randomR (fromEnum min, fromEnum max) g

instance Random Coin where
        random = boundedRandom
        randomR = enumRandomR
```

The best part is, for any type implementing both `Enum` and `Bounded`, this is plug-n-play!

```
data Suite
        = Spade
        | Heart
        | Club
        | Diamond
  deriving (Bounded, Enum)

instance Random Suite where
        random = boundedRandom
        randomR = enumRandomR
```